# Tags: Brand / product name or umbrella term?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 9 questions tagged [ipad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad). Unless it was really the only product of its kind, why not use the umbrella term instead? In this case, [tablet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet) or, if you prefer, [tablet-computer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet-computer). While [ipad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) is easily understandable, it still feels unnecessary for us to promote a product.

<sub>Not that it has any impact, but it's more about the principle, and about remaining neutral, if possible.</sub>

---

The one other case I noticed is [pediasure](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pediasure) (child nutrition). There are two questions:

[Is PediaSure okay for toddlers and if not how to get them off it?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24340/30519)

This one directly concerns PediaSure.

[What are some good food options for a one year-old?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/26848/30519)

I'm not sure why this got that tag, though (they actually mention two other brands in their question). So that tag could be removed.

Then, only one question remains - one tag for one question may not be necessary.

---

My question is

**Shall we try to remain as neutral as possible with regards to tags?**
(this doesn't exclude the possibility that such a brand-/product-tag may be useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that I care about "neutrality" per se, I think that's really not important here.  Having a tag doesn't imply endorsing a product.  If there's a reason to have a tag for the particular product, then it's fine to.

That said, I think in this particular case it's fine to make [ipad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) a synonym of [tablet-computer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet-computer).  I'd be concerned about [tablet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet) because it's a common word for another thing people might ask about (medicine); ideally that would be blacklisted or removed.

Comment: By remaining neutral, the tag is both, meaningful and inclusive (of all other possible tablet computers). This is, in my opinion, the optimal situation (we wouldn't want special tags for every product, would we?). That's unless there is really a decisive difference with regards to parenting between one product and all other products of the same type (I do not know if something like this exists. A made up example: One special stroller with a propeller allowing a child to fly through the air and common enough to raise many parenting questions about airborne toddlers.). I agree with the tag name.

Comment: [Here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24242/30519) we go.

Comment: What I mean is that if we had (many) questions that were specific to the iPad (and not other tablets), then we should have a tag for [tag:iPad].  Questions about iPad parental controls, perhaps, or about using iPads in schools (there's an Apple program for that), etc.  I don't think we have many questions that are iPad specific that wouldn't be appropriate for tablets as well, however.